# Image of prime and maximal ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Suppose we have a homomorphism $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ where $A$ and $B$ are rings. $\phi$ is injective and not necessarily surjective. Is image of prime ideal and maximal ideals in $A$ also prime and maximal in $B$?

My attempt: Suppose $P$ is prime ideal of $A$ then $\phi(a)\phi(b) \in \phi(P)$ then $ab \in P$ and hence $a \in P$ or $b \in P$ which implies $\phi(a) \in P$ or $\phi(b) \in P$.

Is this proof correct? Also how can proceed for maximal ideal.

Comment: Hint: consider the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: As for your attempt, your mistake is that not all elements of $B$ are in the image of $\phi$. If $\phi$ is injective then $\phi(P)$ will be a prime ideal of the image $\phi(A)$, but not necessary of $B$.

Comment: For prime ideal it looks true. For maximal ideal since there is no maximal ideal in Q the proposition seems false.

Comment: My example shows that the claim is false for both prime and maximal ideals. $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, and so it has only the trivial ideals. So the image of any nonzero prime/maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ will not be an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$ at all.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry my bad.

Comment: But can you explain in detail your second comment, I am still not able to see my mistake.

Comment: First of all, you should have tried to prove the image is even an ideal (as I explained, it might not be), before even trying to show it has to be prime. But let's check the prime condition. Suppose $xy\in\phi(P)$. This means there is some $c\in P$ such that $xy=\phi(c)$. This is all we can conclude. What you said is that there are $a,b$ such that $\phi(a)=x$ and $\phi(b)=y$. But this might not be the case, because $\phi$ is not necessary surjective. (and so $x,y$ might not belong to the image of $\phi$)

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining.